# How to work out why javascript code is not working by putting stops in it

Tags: javascript

I am doing a job which involves javascript code that I didn't write.

Currently I am stuck because the javascript code doesn't 'work', instead of me putting all the code onto here and asking why it doesn't work I would like to know how to stop the code to see if it is working -

At the moment I am using

```
  alert("This code is good so far.");
```

but now I'm up to a class constructor and something, somewhere, isn't talking to the database. :(

Comment: Press F12 to open the dev tools on your browser.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:mysql]?

Comment: @David - Good point, mysql referance has been edited out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try using `console.log()` with firefox or chrome. Works way better than alerts.

```
console.log('HUGE ERRORROR!!!!!!!!!');
```

Comment: The message would be much clearer in you logged `FATAL ERRORROR!!!!!!!` instead. ;p

Comment: Updated post to reflect suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome and Firebug (Firefox) (and probably later versions of IE as well) have good **debuggers** built in that will allow you *stop* and *step through* your code. Learn it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to  stop the code at some point you can use `throw new Error("my error");`
and combining it with console.log will help you step through your code step by step.